# JQuery AJAX Function working in Chrome and IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have the following JQuery AJAX Function, which works perfectly in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. Indeed, in this Browser, I receive a “ProcessData is not defined” error message upon executing the function. Shouldn’t Firefox wait for the results before calling the ProcessData Function, as it appears to be doing in the other two Browsers? What do I need to add in order to have this Function work in Firefox?

```
  $(function() {
     $.ajax({
       url: "https://...&callback=?",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: ProcessData
     });
  });

    
  function ProcessData(result) {

  }
```

Comment: I know it's probably not a _real_ solution to your question, but why not just change the order and place `ProcessData` inside the `$(document).ready(...)` shorthand, and before the ajax call? I think it might be a scope issue, not a "timing" issue inside FF.

Comment: Update: I can't reconstruct the problem inside Firefox15: http://jsfiddle.net/qSJew/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion and comment. I was able to solve the issue by adding the logic of the ProcessData Function itself within the $.ajax() Scope itself, as hereafter reproduced:

```
  success: function ProcessData(result) {
    //logic
  }
```